# Which is more effective - three mushrooms at once or one at a time?

Tags: mario-kart-64

In Mario Kart 64, you can get the Triple Mushroom Power up. I am wondering if I should use all three Mushrooms at the same time, or one at a time, after the boost runs out?

I tried both methods but can’t figure out the most effective way to use the Mushrooms.

Answer (score 8):

Using them separately is the most effective way. The speed of the mushrooms does not compound so it is more beneficial to space them out.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The game has a "using mushroom" state for each player and everytime you use a mushroom, it just resets the timer for the boost.  Use a mushroom in the middle of a previous boost and you lose the remaining time on the last mushroom you used when the timer resets.